# Tomcat не запускает проект

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

Запускаю этот проект через Tomcat https://github.com/CaymanJava/online_banking

Выдает ошибку

> ОШИБКА - Application at context path [/online_banking] could not be
>   started

Подскажите из-за чего это может быть

Система 32бит

Comment: Сегодня, к сожалению, все телепаты в отпуске :), поэтому лучше будет привести лог томката.

Comment: Если возникает ошибка времени выполнения

Comment: @apper приложи логи, лежат в папке `/logs` в директории с tomcat'ом

Comment: @Темкатоже Посмотрите пожалуйста в этой теме https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/952126/tomcat-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5

Comment: @Sergi посмотрите пожалуйста в этой теме https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/952126/tomcat-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5